# Site with statistics of publications/citations per country?

Tags: publications, citations, website

I'm looking for a site (other than [Scimago](http://www.scimagojr.com/)) that presents statistics of published papers and/or citations per country. However, I need more detail than that presented in Scimago. Ideally, I would like to have a list of authors, or the list of papers per country (having all the statistics that Scimago shows is a plus).

Is there any site that provides such information?

Comment: Dare I ask _why_ you need this?

Comment: @JeffE yes you can ask. Actually, I'm doing some survey regarding the publication status of some developing countries, so I wanted more detailed information of the respective fields in the country. Such as active authors, and what are they publishing, etc. Thus, I don't think I will get a huge volume of data.

Comment: [microsoft.academic](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/) is always a great resource. If I had the silverlight plugin I could verify that [Academic Map](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/AcademicMap) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Gopi: That was a great comment; please add it as an answer.

Comment: @Bravo, as stated, I cannot verify what I am saying since I do not have the microsoft plugin (and do not want to install it) so I would rather have someone being able to verify it put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are asking can be carried out using Web of Science. I used address == "Canada" for the past 5 years, and immediately had published records for 241, 711 articles! You can ask for a citation report, which provides the information that Scimago has at the top. I think the issue you'll face is the sheer volume of data you're asking for. Even limiting the category to "ecology" (my field) yields over 3000 articles.

Of course, this answer won't be much use if your university doesn't have access to WoS.

The other thought I had was using Harzing's Publish or Perish (http://www.harzing.com/index.htm) which uses Google Scholar data. I tried a direct google scholar search, but can't immediately see how to limit it to articles *published* by people in the country as opposed to being about the country.

I hadn't heard of Microsoft Academic Search (see comment by Gopi) - so I had a look. The short answer is yes, it will show you publications by geographic region, but you have to go in by institution. You can get a google scholar like list of papers - and export those in various formats, but I only found the export option at the level of individual author. 
For example, Université du Burundi has 16 publications by 5 authors, with an H-index of 4. 
Pretty cool map though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Gopi's comment, here's a snapshot of [Academic map](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/AcademicMap) at work. I could only see the cumulative publication count in every field; but from the highlight of a few Indian universities I doubt if any quality measure has been considered at all. Also it lacks the cumulative country statistic and the citation counts you ask for.

[image]